# How to Install Selenium on Eclipse (Java) with WebDriver for Chrome Windows 10

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10

How do I install Selenium on Windows10 with WebDriver for Chrome?
I didn't find a full tutorial for that and I keep getting this error:

[image]

And this Exception in Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.chrome.FatalChromeException: Cannot create chrome driver
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeCommandExecutor.start(ChromeCommandExecutor.java:382)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.startClient(ChromeDriver.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:85)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:25)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:53)
    at Priority_Automation.MyAutomation.main(MyAutomation.java:18)
```

This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class MyAutomation {
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        //options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
        
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
  "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Selenuim\\chromedriver");
         ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
        System.out.println("Testing");
            
    }

}
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't see any compilation errors, it seems installation of Selenium within Eclipse IDE or configuration of Selenium jars within Eclipse IDE have no issues.

However, as you are in [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) environment within the `System.setProperty()` line you need to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) executable including the extension i.e. *`exe`*.

So effectively, your line of code will be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Selenuim\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Additionally, which invoking the url through *`get()`* you need to pass the complete url as:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```